# Integrate (e(-0.08)×0.8)^t w.r.t t

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How do you work it out? I know the answer is ((e^(-0.08)*0.8)^t)/ log(e^(-0.08)*0.8)   but how do we get there?

Also, why can you not just calculate (0.8×e^(-0.08)) and let that equal x. Now, integral of x^t= (x^t+1)/t+1 ?

Comment: $\int x^t\,\mathrm dt$ is not $x^{t+1}/(t+1)$, but $\int x^t \mathrm dx$ is.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Write $0.8e^{0.08}=k$ so you have to integrate $k^t$ with respect to $t$. But $k^t=e^{t \log(k)}$.

I am sure that you can take from here.